# How to customise Show/Read instances on the lines of FromJSON/ToJSON

Tags: haskell, generics, typeclass

I have the following sum type

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Casing
import GHC.Generics

data OrderType = Confirmed | AwaitingShipping | Shipped
  deriving (Eq, Generic)

instance ToJSON OrderType where
  toJSON = genericToJSON $ (aesonPrefix snakeCase){constructorTagModifier=(camelTo2 '_')}
```

This results in the following conversion during JSON encoding:

```
Confirmed => confirmed
AwaitingShipping => awaiting_shipping
Shipped => shipped
```

How do I quickly generate a `Show` instance that has the exact same `OrderType` => `String` conversion?

Please note, I know I can do the following, but I'm looking for a way to avoid this boilerplate.

```
instance Show OrderType where
  show Confirmed = "confirmed"
  show AwaitingShipping = "awaiting_shipping"
  show Shipped = "shipped"
```

Comment: Why does it have to be an instance of `Show`? How about deriving the standard `Show`, and then composing `camelTo2 '_' . show`?

Comment: Clever! Let me try...

Comment: I redefined `ToJSON` via the standard `Show` instance and it works perfectly fine. `instance ToJSON TxnSource where toJSON = toJSON.(camelTo2 '_').show` So, this technique can be used at other places as well. Any idea how to do this for `FromJSON`?

Comment: Taking the inverses I would look for something like `read . toCamel . fromJSON`, except the last bit is actually `parseJSON` and it is monadic: `instance FromJSON TxnSource where parseJSON = fmap (read . toCamel) . parseJSON`. You need to define `toCamel` doing the inverse of `camelTo2 '_'`. You probably want to use `readMaybe` too.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm wondering. How does `FromJSON` use the same `camelTo` function during parsing? Here's the `FromJSON` instance that does the camel<>Haskell conversion absolutely fine -- `  parseJSON = genericParseJSON $ (aesonPrefix snakeCase){constructorTagModifier=(camelTo2 '_')}`

Comment: This is what I'm trying to understand next -- https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/549

Answer (score 2):

(I've edited my answer to have significantly more explanations. If you just want a module containing the code, it's [still available](https://gist.github.com/kosmikus/f00cecac50a8e240c7fd8ef764b8c69e).

The question aims at changing the default `Show` and `Read` instances for
enumeration types such as `OrderType` and providing custom ones. I'll show
below how that can be done, although in principle I advise against doing so,
because `Show` and `Read` are typically supposed to produce Haskell
representations of the values. I'll also suggest a different solution,
however, by going via new type classes.

My solution is similar to the one proposed by Li-yao Xia, but based on [generics-sop](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop) rather than built-in GHC generics.

We are using the following module header.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module CustomShowEnum where

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Data.Maybe
import Generics.SOP
import Generics.SOP.NS
import Generics.SOP.TH
import Text.Read
```

Let's start with a function that computes a product (a list
with a statically known number of elementS) of all the
constructor names.

```
conNames ::
  forall a proxy .
  (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a)
  => proxy a -> NP (K String) (Code a)
conNames _ =
  hmap
    (K . constructorName)
    (constructorInfo (datatypeInfo (Proxy @a)))
```

The `datatypeInfo` function provides all meta-information
about a given datatype, the `constructorInfo` function extracts
from that a product with meta-information about each
constructor. We are only interested in the names, nothing else,
so we use `hmap` over the product to extract the constructor
names in each position.

Let's see how we can use it:

```
GHCi> conNames (Proxy @Bool)
K "False" :* (K "True" :* Nil)
```

Read `Nil` as the empty product, and `:*` as "cons". Each element
is wrapped in a `K` constructor, because it is a product containing
a (constant) String for every constructor of the datatype.

The same works on other datatypes:

```
GHCi> conNames (Proxy @Ordering)
K "LT" :* (K "EQ" :* (K "GT" :* Nil))
GHCi> conNames (Proxy @(Maybe ()))
K "Nothing" :* (K "Just" :* Nil)
```

We can also make it work on the `OrderType` mentioned in the question:

```
data OrderType = Confirmed | AwaitingShipping | Shipped
```

But if we try this blindly, then we get an error that we have no
instances for the `Generic` and `HasDatatypeInfo` classes. For
generics-sop functions to work, types must be an instance of these
classes. One way to achieve this is to use Template Haskell:

```
deriveGeneric ''OrderType
```

(Another way for people who dislike Template Haskell is mentioned in
the library documentation.)

Now, we can use `conNames`:

```
GHCi> conNames (Proxy @OrderType)
K "Confirmed" :* (K "AwaitingShipping" :* (K "Shipped" :* Nil))
```

A variant of this is a function that takes a specific value, and computes
the outermost constructor that built that value.

```
conName ::
  forall a .
  (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a)
  => a -> String
conName x =
  hcollapse
    (hzipWith
      const
      (conNames (Proxy @a))
      (unSOP (from x))
    )
```

Here, we use `from` to compute the generic representation of the given
value, which is a sum of products. The sum encodes a choice between one
of the constructors of the datatype. We can use `hzipWith` to combine a
compatible product (a product of n values) and sum (a choice of option
i out of n possible options), and it will select the i'th position of
the product and combine the two. By using `const` to combine the two,
the effect is that we'll just return the constructor name corresponding
to the given constructor from our `conNames` product. The `hcollapse`
application in the end extracts the single `String` value.

Let's look at a number of examples again:

```
GHCi> conName Confirmed
"Confirmed"
GHCi> conName (Just 3)
"Just"
GHCi> conName [1,2,3]
":"
```

Note that in the last example, the list is, on the top-level, just an
application of cons.

Next, we define a function `enum` that computes a product of all
the values of an enumeration type. This is similar to `conNames`,
but rather than returning the constructor names (as strings), we
return the actual constructors.

```
enum ::
  forall a .
  (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a, All ((~) '[]) (Code a))
  => NP (K a) (Code a)
enum =
  hmap
    (mapKK to)
    (apInjs'_POP (POP (hcpure (Proxy @((~) '[])) Nil)))
```

The `apInks'_POP` function produces a product of all the constructor
functions in their generic representation. These still have to be
applied to a representation of their arguments, and we need to provide
these arguments as a product of products (a two-dimensional table
with one row per constructor, each row containing the arguments
to be applied to that particular constructors).

Fortunately, we restrict ourselves to enumeration types here. These
are types without any constructor arguments. This is expressed
by the constraint `All ((~) '[]) (Code a)`. The code of a type is
a list of list of types. The outer list contains an entry per
constructor, the inner lists give the types of the constructor
arguments. The constraint states that each of the inner lists must
be empty, which is equivalent to each of the constructors having
no arguments.

We can therefore produce a product of empty argument lists,
which is what we do via `POP (hcpure (Proxy (@((~) '[])) Nil))`.

Finally, we use `hmap` with `to` to turn each of the constructed
values back from their generic representation into their original
shape.

Let's look at examples:

```
GHCi> enum @Bool
K False :* (K True :* Nil)
```

Compare this again with

```
GHCi> conNames (Proxy @Bool)
K "False" :* (K "True" :* Nil)
```

and note that in one case, we return strings, in the other, we
return actual values.

```
GHCi> enum @Ordering
K LT :* (K EQ :* (K GT :* Nil))
```

If we try to apply `enum` to a type that is not an enumeration
type, we get a type error.

If we try to apply `enum` to `OrderType`, we get an error that a
`Show` instance for `OrderType` is lacking.

If we derive one via

```
deriving instance Show OrderType
```

we obtain:

```
GHCi> enum @OrderType
K Confirmed :* (K AwaitingShipping :* (K Shipped :* Nil))
```

If we use the custom `Show` instance that was desired in the
question and that I show how to define below, we instead get

```
GHCi> enum @OrderType
K confirmed :* K awaiting_shipping :* K shipped :* Nil
```

This also demonstrates why it might not be such a good idea
to change the instance, because we now see that the output of
`show` used by GHCi to print back the result mixes standard
Haskell notation with special notation intended to be used
in a particular domain.

Before we go there, however, let's first implement one final
utility function that we'll need for the parsing direction:

```
conTable ::
  forall a .
  (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a, All ((~) '[]) (Code a))
  => [(String, a)]
conTable =
  hcollapse
    (hzipWith
      (mapKKK (,))
      (conNames (Proxy @a))
      enum
    )
```

The `conTable` function computes a lookup table associating
the string constructor names with the actual values. We have
the functions to compute the two products, `conNames` and
`enum`. We use `hzipWith` with `(,)` to pair them. The result
is another product, but because the product contains the same
type in every position, we can use `hcollapse` to turn it into
a normal Haskell list.

```
GHCi> conTable @Bool
[("False", False), ("True", True)]
GHCi> conTable @Ordering
[("LT", LT), ("EQ", EQ), ("GT", GT)]
GHCi> conTable @OrderType
[("Confirmed", Confirmed), ("AwaitingShipping", AwaitingShipping), ("Shipped", Shipped)]
```

The final example is using the default / derived `Show` instance.

With these ingredients in place, we are now able to implement
custom `show` and `read` replacements for enumeration types.
The `show` direction quite easy:

```
customShowEnum ::
  forall a .
  (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a, All ((~) '[]) (Code a))
  => (String -> String)
  -> a -> String
customShowEnum f = f . conName
```

Given a value, we use `conName` to determine its constructor and
then apply the given conversion function to the result.

This function would work for all types in `Generic` and
`HasDatatypeInfo`, so the `All ((~) '[]) (Code a)` constraint
that restricts it to enumeration types is optional.

Here are a few examples:

```
GHCi> customShowEnum id AwaitingShipping
"AwaitingShipping"
GHCi> customShowEnum reverse Confirmed
"demrifnoC"
GHCi> customShowEnum (camelTo2 '_') AwaitingShipping
"awaiting_shipping"
```

For the `read` replacement, we implement a function that can
be used to defined the `readPrec` method of the `Read` class.
This produces a parser of type `ReadPrec a`:

```
readPrec :: Read a => ReadPrec a
```

The basic strategy is as follows: We start from the lookup table
given by `conTable`. We adjust the strings in this lookup table
using the same conversion function that we also used in
`customShowEnum`. Given an input string, we then try to find
it in the adjusted lookup table, and if we find it, we return
the associated value. The code looks as follows:

```
customReadEnum ::
  forall a .
  (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a, All ((~) '[]) (Code a))
  => (String -> String)
  -> ReadPrec a
customReadEnum f =
  let
    adjustedTable :: [(Lexeme, a)]
    adjustedTable = map (\ (n, x) -> (Ident (f n), x)) conTable
  in
    parens $ do
      n <- lexP
      maybe pfail return (lookup n adjustedTable)
```

This essentially follows the description above: `parens`
additionally allows the constructor name to be wrapped in
parentheses, as is generally allowed by `read`, and the use
of `lexP` additionally handles whitespace. If the `lookup`
in the table fails, we let the parser fail using `pfail`.

If we want to try this, we have to run the `ReadPrec` parser
by applying `readPrec_to_S`, which then expects a precedence
level (irrelevant in this case) and an input string and returns
a list of pairs containing pairs of possible parses and remaining
strings:

```
GHCi> readPrec_to_S (customReadEnum @OrderType id) 0 "AwaitingShipping"
[(AwaitingShipping, "")]
GHCi> readPrec_to_S (customReadEnum @OrderType (camelTo2 '_')) 0 "AwaitingShipping"
[]
GHCi> readPrec_to_S (customReadEnum @OrderType (camelTo2 '_')) 0 "awaiting_shipping"
[(AwaitingShipping, "")]
>>> readPrec_to_S (customReadEnum @OrderType (camelTo2 '_')) 0 "   ( awaiting_shipping)  "
[(AwaitingShipping, "  ")]
```

If we now wanted to use `customReadShow` and `customReadEnum` to
define the `Show` and `Read` instance for `OrderType`, we could do
this simply as follows:

```
instance Show OrderType where
  show = customShowEnum (camelTo2 '_')

instance Read OrderType where
  readPrec = customReadEnum (camelTo2 '_')
```

However, as I said above, I'd advise to just use the derived instances
here to avoid confusion, and for the domain-specific textual representation,
I would just introduce new classes, for example:

```
class ToString a where
  toString :: a -> String

class FromString a where
  fromString :: String -> Maybe a

instance ToString OrderType where
  toString = customShowEnum (camelTo2 '_')

customFromString ::
  forall a .
  (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a, All ((~) '[]) (Code a))
  => (String -> String)
  -> String -> Maybe a
customFromString f x =
  case readPrec_to_S (customReadEnum f) 0 x of
    [(r, "")] -> Just r
    _         -> Nothing

instance FromString OrderType where
  fromString = customFromString (camelTo2 '_')
```

We could also go a few steps further:

- We could use default signatures that map `toString` and `fromString` either
  to the default `Show` / `Read` behaviour, or to our custom behaviour, so that
  we can provide empty instances or using deriving in the more common of the
  two cases.
- We could use a third class to associate a particular conversion function with
  a given type and use this class in our generic definitions, to make it more
  obvious that the same function is used for both directions and thereby remove
  a source of potential errors.

Comment: This is a gem of an answer. I'm going through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQxH349HOik to be able to understand and completely internalise Generics SOP. Is it alright if I ask follow-up questions via these comments?

Comment: First question -- what's with `@Foo` syntax. It's the first time I'm seeing this.

Comment: In the video, most examples deal with the `I` constructor. What is the `K` constructor for? What others are there and is there a document describing the differences?

Comment: The `@Foo` syntax is a type application, available since GHC 8. If you have any polymorphic function, you can use `@<sometype>` to instantiate it. So, for example `id @Char :: Char -> Char`. In practice, this can often be used in situation where you would otherwise need extra type annotations or even proxies in order to help the GHC type checker.

Comment: The `I` constructor is identity, defined `newtype I a = I a`. The `K` constructor is for "constant, define `newtype K c a = K c`. In practice, if you parameterize one of the `NP`-like structures by `I`, you get a heterogeneous structure, containing in every position what the index list indicates. If you instantiate it to `K Something`, you get a homogeneous structure containing a `Something` in every position.

Comment: If you want more material on generics-sop, there's another (slightly more application-oriented) talk here: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/10181-fun-with-sum-and-product-types There's also a longer document explaining a lot of type-level background here: https://github.com/kosmikus/SSGEP

Comment: Quick question -- will all of this infra work with types/constructors will 32 fields or less? I just did a `:i Code` and saw that the instances go only up to 32-tuples. We have records (representing DB tables) that have more than 40 fields.

Comment: I'm royally confused about why the result type of `conNames` would be an NP (*product*) and not NS (*sum*). It's deal with the various constructors of a sum-type -- shouldn't the resultant _thing_ be a sum, and not a product? Also, if in `conNames` I change `K` to `I`, why doesn't it work?

Comment: There's an (arbitrary) limit for actual tuples, so if you're using tuples with more than 32 components, extra instances would have to be added. But if an enumeration type has more than 32 components, or a constructor has more than 32 arguments, then deriving an SOP `Generic` instance should still work.

Comment: An `NP` is a generalization of a tuple, and contains a combination of several things. An `NS` is a generalization of `Either`, and embodies a choice of one of several things. A function returning *all* constructor names of a datatype returns a combination of several things, hence a product and not a sum.

Comment: The choice between `K` or `I` isn't arbitrary. The `conNames` function returns all the constructor names, which are all `String`s, regardless of the composition and types occurring in the datatype definition. Hence `K`.

Comment: I tried understanding what's going on with `hzipWith` by passing this as the first argument `\a b -> trace (show a) a` and was surprised to find that the function is being called only once, irrespective of the number of elements in the SOP structure. Eg, it's called only once even if the structure is `SOP S (S (S (Z Nil)))`

Comment: Shouldn't a heterogenous list be a superset of a homogenous list? i.e. if `K` is acceptable in `conNames`, why is `I` not compiling?

Comment: If you zip an `NP` with an `NS`, then the function is only called once, because the `NS` contains only a single element which is combined with the corresponding element from the product. If you zip two `NP`s, the combining function will be called once per pair of elements, more like you might be used to from `zipWith`.

Comment: No, a heterogeneous list is not a superset of a homogeneous list. Let's look at an example: An `NP I [Int, Char, Bool]` contains three elements, an `I Int`, an `I Char` and an `I Bool`. This is isomorphic to a list containing just an `Int`, a `Char`, and a `Bool`. On the other hand, an `NP (K String) [Int, Char, Bool]` contains three elements, a `K String Int`, a `K String Char`, and a `K String Bool`. This is isomorphic to a list containing three `String`s.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed there was a reason it had to be an instance of `Show`, otherwise `camelTo2 '_' . show` seems to do the job.

In any case, here's how you can get the constructor name with `GHC.Generics`. Then you can write `camelTo2 '_' . constructorName` with no additional setup required; in particular, you are free to use this as an implementation of `show`.

```
import GHC.Generics

-- Constructor name of the value of an ADT.
-- Using 'Generic.from', we map it to a generic representation.
constructorName :: (Generic a, CName (Rep a)) => a -> String
constructorName = cname . from

-- Class of generic representations of ADTs, built using
-- types in GHC.Generics.
-- 'cname' extracts the constructor name from it.
class CName f where
  cname :: f p -> String

-- M1 is a newtype to attach metadata about the type
-- being represented at the type level.
-- The first parameter marks the kind of the data
-- in the second one. 'D' indicates general information
-- like the type name and whether it is a newtype.
-- Here we ignore it and look in the rest of the representation.
instance CName f => CName (M1 D c f) where
  cname (M1 f) = cname f

-- '(:+:)' represents sums.
instance (CName f, CName g) => CName (f :+: g) where
  cname (L1 f) = cname f
  cname (R1 g) = cname g

-- 'M1' again, but 'C' indicates information about a specific
-- constructor, we extract it using the 'GHC.Generics.Constructor'
-- type class.
instance Constructor c => CName (M1 C c f) where
  cname = conName
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand this code. Would it be possible to please add some comments to explain what is conceptually happening here?

Comment: May I trouble you for the reverse, i.e. given a text/string, how to get a constructor name and value from it?